# Why is IntelliJ pom.xml red for profile.no-liquibase and profile.no-swagger?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, swagger, liquibase

Why is my settings in pom.xml in IntelliJ red?

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: where are the settings in red defined?

Comment: Sorry I asked stupid question. That is now defined in properties:-)

Comment: what properties? system properties? please show how they are defined

Comment: Within the pom.xml you can add properties within     <properties> </properties> Also I use IntelliJ and in the Maven Projects tab you can select different Profiles, these the control your variables.

Comment: so show the part where it's defined in <properties> ... its not helping if you post incomplete information

Comment: Here you can read about properties: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-user-defined-properties-in-maven/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use IntelliJ and the settings are defined in maven profiles

[image]

In pom.xml

```
   ...
   <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>no-liquibase</id>
        <properties>
            <profile.no-liquibase>,no-liquibase</profile.no-liquibase>
        </properties>
    </profile>
   ...
```

Spring profile example https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/

Maven profile example https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-user-defined-properties-in-maven/

Selecting them in my IDE and rebuilding the project, it was solved for me.

```
mvn clean install
```